# STM32 L4(Nucleo-144) CAN Tx pin stays high and dosen't transmit any data

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, can, stm32cubemx, hal

I'm new to STM32 and a starting knowledge of C. I'm trying to get some level of CAN communication to be working. I've tried looking up the HAL'S required but for some reason no matter what I do, the CAN_Tx pin just stays high coming out the pin, and doesn't look like it's transferring any data through the oscilloscope. Any help or possible reasoning would be appreciated.

[image: Code]

Comment: I don't understand why you are configuring the controller for remote transmission.  That configuration is used to cause a transmission when a given identifier is received, so no data will be transmitted until then.  I suggest you configure the controller for normal transmission.

Comment: @SteveMathwig hi apologies but where is it that’s configured for remote transmission so that i can learn and change it? Thanks

Comment: pHeader.RTR=CAN_RTR_DATA.  I am not familiar with the STM32 nor its CAN controller, so I cannot tell you specifically how to set a normal transmission, but I do know enough about CAN to know that you don't want a remote transmit request.  That is why I didn't submit an answer, but commented instead.

Comment: @SteveMathwig hi thanks for the comment, i tried swithing to the alternative but neither seem to work

Comment: A quick look at the STM32 data sheet indicates that the TXRQ bit in the pHeader structure needs to be set to request a transmission.

Comment: @SteveMathwig thanks forn the help, i wasnt able to find "txrq" in any of the code/librarys. If your refering to the .RTR , the only two options is CAN_RTR_DATA, OR CAN_RTR_REMOTE. neither seem to work

Comment: Look for TXRQ in the datasheet.  I don't know what libraries you are using, so I really can't help you there.  I may also have been looking at the wrong datasheet.  Let me know the exact processor you are using so I can verify the TXRQ setting.

Comment: @SteveMathwig STM32L496ZG . Thanks

Comment: Okay, it looks like I had the correct documentation for the CAN controller.  Since I don't know how your library code works, I am just going to give you a few pointers to try to narrow down the problem.  First, you need to ensure that the transmit message is being properly formatted into one of the CAN transmit message boxes (ex. CAN_TI0R, CAN_TDT0R, CAN_DTL0R and CAN_TDH0R).  Then, check the status registers (CAN_MSR and CAN_TSR) for any error conditions.  Ensure the NART bit in CAN_MCR is cleared, so the transmitter will keep transmitting until an ACK is received.

Comment: Make sure you look at the error status in CAN_ESR.  The CAN controller won't even attempt to transmit during a bus error condition.  A bus error condition may well indicate a hardware, not firmware problem.

Comment: C code needs to be posted as _text_ not as pictures of text.